# Priority of nested ternary operator in AntlrV4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am using AntlrV4 to build a rule engine. But the priority of nested ternary operator without bracket is confusing. Here is the grammar fragment:

```
expression QUESTION_MARK expression COLON expression                # ternaryexpr
```

Here is a nested example:

```
1 > 0 ? 2 : 3 > 0 ? 4 : 5
```

The result in Java & NodeJS is equal to `1 > 0 ? 2 : (3 > 0 ? 4 : 5)`

However the result from antlrV4 is equal to `(1 > 0 ? 2 : 3 > 0) ? 4 : 5`。 Is there any solution to solve this without adding bracket manually?

Comment: Try what is done in the [java/java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/ef698f1a02103d7e026ce7b3ea0b4120d4fc487c/java/java/JavaParser.g4#L620) using `<assoc=right>`.

Comment: Thanks kaby76, assoc is the right way to solve this~~~